# Apple "Cinema HD Display" (DVI) not recognized by MacBook Pro (late 2013)

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport, cinema-display, dvi

My new [MacBook Pro (late 2013)](http://support.apple.com/kb/SP690) refuses to recognize an Apple [30-inch Apple Cinema HD Display](http://support.apple.com/kb/sp79).

That monitor has only a DVI cable. I am using a new Apple-brand Mini DisplayPort to DVI adapter. When I unplug the adapter, my Mac's screen flashes as if it noticed a monitor was detached. But at no point does the external display show anything. The monitor's power light is on. The USB pass-through works for the keyboard. I've tried both of the MacBook Pro's Mini DisplayPort ports.

Tried the old reliable ⌥+⌘+P+R to hear the startup bong noise three times. No go.

The monitor works when plugging the same Mini DisplayPort adapter into a MacBook Air the older OS, 10.8.5.

Confusingly, my new MacBook Pro works well with another Apple monitor, the 24-inch Cinema display with built-in Mini DisplayPort cable and LED backlighting.

So the problem lies with either:

- the MacBook's hardware, or
- Mavericks

…failing to handle a DVI monitor (even an Apple-branded DVI monitor).

Comment: I posted this question because I did about 20 minutes of googling with no answer. I found similar discussions (⌥+⌘+P+R, plugging cable early or later), but no fixes that worked for me.

Comment: Mavericks has originally screwed some external displays. Most it was fixed in 10.9.3. I can help you reading the Console report if you publish it. But do so from the moment (time stamp) when you plug in the external monitor and then some 30 lines after that.